# Simple recursive program freezes computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, freeze

My simple recursive progaram which updates a dictionary freezes the whole computer for a long time.  I wrote a script to find a all prime factors and their counts, and get them in to a dictionary.

For example: if N = p<sup>n</sup> x q<sup>m</sup>

then dictionary should be: `{ 1:1 , p:n , q:m }`

My code works for small numbers, but for large numbers, such as 54365765878, it freezes the computer for long times and the task manager shows my script uses 1.4 Gb of RAM out of 2 Gb.

This is my code:

```
M=int(input('Enter M\n'))

M_fac={1:1}

def fac_rec(m):
    global M_fac
    for d in [k for k in range(2,int(m//2)+1)]+[int(m)]:
        if m%d==0 and d!=1:
            if d in M_fac:
                M_fac[d]+=1
            else:
                M_fac[d]=1
            fac_rec(m/d)
            break

fac_rec(M)

print(M_fac)
```

What is the matter with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible use of recursion!

Now that that's out of the way, I believe the problem with your code is this line:

```
for d in [k for k in range(2,int(m//2)+1)]+[int(m)]:
```

Instead of simply looping over this (potentially large) range of numbers, we're creating actual lists that have to be stored in memory.  (Over and over recursively.)  I understand that the reason for this is the appended term is necessary if `m` is prime.  But let's redesign the code to avoid creating this list (and other tweaks):

```
from collections import defaultdict

M = int(input('Enter M: '))

M_fac = defaultdict(int, {1: 1})

def fac_rec(m):
    global M_fac

    for d in range(2, m // 2 + 1):
        if m % d == 0:
            M_fac[d] += 1

            fac_rec(m // d)
            return

    M_fac[m] += 1  # m is prime!

fac_rec(M)

print(dict(M_fac))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Enter M: 54365765878
{1: 1, 2: 1, 29: 1, 89: 1, 163: 1, 64613: 1}
>
```

**VERIFICATION**

```
> dc
1 2 * 29 * 89 * 163 * 64613 * p
54365765878
>
```